# Jeremy Kemp (Robert Picard in ST:TNG), RIP

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

British actor Jeremy Kemp [died on July 24th](https://comicbook.com/2019/07/24/jeremy-kemp-dead-star-trek-the-next-generation-family-robert-pic/?fbclid=IwAR2OoFGOEykCBoTDt3fRAqAY_PT9_g9CCa4XHaFULOq2nTWBhTy8XSwLaOc) of this year.  A prolific actor best known for dramatic roles in mini-series and television, he also had a couple of notable Sci-Fi appearances.

Kemp turned in a memorable performance Jean-Luc Picard's elder brother in the TNG episode "Family."  He was also well-received for his portrayal as the guilt-ridden scientist Ernst Queller in the SPACE:1999 episode "Voyager's Return."

[image: Kemp as Robert Picard]

[image]